# Locate an HTML element that match 2 attribute values (selenium c#)

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

*I want to locate an element by it's **href** but since there is many elements with the same **href**, therefore I would like to specify another attribute that matches that element **e.g.** (**href** and __class_ that will make this element unique.)*

```
 FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'bla bla') and a//[contains(@href, 'My element')]"));

<div class="bla bla">

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="test">Our job</li>
                    <li><a href="/123">123</a></li>
```

*What I am looking for is the element with href " **/123** "*

*Any suggestion how can I make this work ?*

Comment: could you provide the corresponding HTML structure? where we can see several of your a-elements

Comment: @drkthng I amended my post please check the block of code above

Comment: Use `CSQuery` It's a lot easier. It uses CSS selectors.

Comment: your example only contains one link element and thus only one unique href on the site. But in your text you write that you have several elements with the same href. You might consider expanding your example a bit more.

Comment: @drkthng Lets speak English it might be easier, In this <div clas="bla bla"> find me a Href(/123) how would you explain that to the computer :) ?

Comment: @Mystia updated my answer, have a look

Comment: Using CSQuery you only need `dom.Select("div.bla.bla a[href=\"/123\"]")[0]` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your description:

> What I am looking for is this href(/123)

this is how to find it:

```
WebElement blabla = driver.findElement(By.className("bla bla"));
blabla.findElement(By.linkText("123"));
```

or in one go via xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'bla bla']//a[@href = '/123']"));
```

BUT in your text you said several of your links have the same href? Your example only contains one link and thus a unique href.
If this is the case, you would need to look for more unique locators in the parent elements.

Above is Java, so to stay in your first line of C# code do the following changes:

```
FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'bla bla')]//a[contains(@href, 'My element')]"));
```

Comment: I just gave an example what I am trying to achieve and that is to specify in which <div> my <a> is . I can't search by link text because I have multiple hrefs with same text.

Comment: well as I said, you need to expand your example, otherwise no one knows, what elements could be used to distinguish your links...

Comment: Thank you , the last piece of c# code was the thing I was looking for.